# How to make two pcs invisible to each other with switch?

Tags: switch

Here's my architecture

[image]

The switch is simplest, cheapest one, I don't think it has some web interface

How can I make pc1 and pc2 not seeing each others?

basically in two different networks

or what I'd need to buy?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic for [networkengineering.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

An unmanaged switch has no filtering facility, so you can't prevent those end hosts from talking to each other. If you insist on using unmanaged switches you require a second one, without connection to the first.

Depending on its feature set, a managed switch may offer various methods to separate the hosts, including VLANs (separate L2 segments/broadcast domains), private VLAN or port separation (directly inhibit traffic between switch ports), or ACLs (filtering by L3 addresses).

For a weak separation, you could put each host in its own IPv4 subnet (e.g. 192.168.0.2/25 and 192.168.0.130/25) but that doesn't inhibit L2 traffic at all or prevent a user from reconfiguring the addresses. For IPv6, that's a bit harder to separate due to the use of link-local addresses.